# Can't change width of dropdown using Chosen plugin

Tags: html, css, forms, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chose plugin and was styling it, but met this issue:

[image]

It is caused by this generate HTML:

```
    <div id="sel1WY_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 300px;>
//this is width of container
  <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 298.333px; top: 22.3333px;">
//this is html of dropdown
```

How can I fix it ? Also it could be caused by additional border, yes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I managed do find it very fast)

**ADDED**

```
 .chzn-container-single .chzn-single {
border: 1px solid rgba(98,141, 40, 0.5);
}
```

**DELETE**

```
   .chzn-container {
       border: 1px solid rgba(98,141, 40, 0.5);}
```